# JavaScript prototypal inheritance: succinct syntax?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

Is there a more succinct way to express this than three distinct, procedural operations? Something more object notation-like, or at least all within the body of the `Name` function?

Problem:

```
function Name(first, last) {
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
}

Name.prototype = new String;

Name.prototype.toString = function() {
   return this.last + ', ' + this.first;
};
```

Test:

```
console.log(new Name("jimmy", "dean").toString())
console.log(new Name() instanceof Name);
console.log(new Name() instanceof String);
console.log(new Name() instanceof Object);
console.log(Name.prototype.toString.call(new Name('jimmy', 'dean')));
console.log(Name.prototype.toString.call({
    first: 'jimmy',
    last: 'dean'
}));
```

Expected output:

```
< "dean, jimmy"
< true
< true
< true
< "dean, jimmy"
< "dean, jimmy"
```

Comment: Nitpicking; do you mean `partFirst` instead?

Comment: @pimvdb—sometimes it's better to just edit the question for small typos.

Comment: I don't understand why you want the prototype to be an instance of String. As long as *toString* returns a string (which seems to be sensible), then you can call any method that would be inherited from String without the assignment of a string to the constructor's prototype.

Answer (score 1):

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wKvqQ/9/)**

```
function Name(first, last) {
    this.partFirst = first;
    this.partLast = last;
    this.valueOf = this.toString = function() {
        return this.partLast + ', ' + this.partFirst;
    }
}
Name.prototype = new String();
```

Comment: Your method does not inherit its prototype from the `String` constructor any more. Side note: A `valueOf` method has to be defined, to prevent the following error: `String.prototype.valueOf called on incompatible Object` (FF 8.0, using `""+(new Name())` as a test case).

Comment: noted, but explicitly calling `.toString()` as the OP intends to works fine.  And wouldn't a parameter-less constructor call for `Name` be a programmer error?  Updated link above to show `(new Name("first", "last") + "")`

Comment: `new Name`, `new Name()` and `new Name(void 0, void 0)` are equivalent and valid *(`void 0 === undefined`, by the way)*. As for the error, it occurs when using the OP's inheritance concept: http://jsfiddle.net/wKvqQ/4/

Comment: @RobW found that the `String.toString()` uses the `valueOf` so all you have to do is define the `valueOf`. check link above again.

Comment: Just define both methods, if you like the current way: `this.valueOf = this.toString = ..`, to also account for an [explicit](http://jsfiddle.net/wKvqQ/7/) `.toString()` call. However, setting a prototype instead of using `this.____ = ` is more [efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493252/javascript-prototype-operator-performance-saves-memory-but-is-it-faster) and readable.

Comment: @Raynos did he specify that he needed prototypical OO ?

Comment: @jondavidjohn it's in the title and it is prototypical OO after you edited the question.

Comment: @Raynos does my solution not utilize prototypal inheritance? Does it not provide the desired solution? What is this then `Name.prototype = new String();`?

Comment: @jondavidjohn your right, it does use prototypical OO. It didn't in the earlier version and I can't remove downvotes unless it's been edited ;)

Comment: The point is Name.prototype.toString.call(instance) will not return "{lastname}, {firstname}" with this proposed solution. It's not multi-depth prototypal inheritance.

Comment: Now that you have updated the requirements... My answer to your question is **No**

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use `Object.create`.

```
var Name = Object.create(String.prototype, {
  toString: { value: function _toString() {
    return this.partLast + ', ' + this.partFirst;
  } },
  constructor: { value: function _constructor(first, last) {
    this.partFirst = first;
    this.partLast = last;
    return this;
  } }
});

var name = Object.create(Name).constructor("foo", "bar");
```

Now ES5 is a bit ugly, so you can use [some mechanism for ES5 OO sugar](http://raynos.org/blog/17/Improving-ES5-OO-with-sugar), let's take [pd](https://github.com/Raynos/pd) as an example:

```
var Name = pd.make(String.prototype, {
  toString: function _toString() {
    return this.partLast + ', ' + this.partFirst;
  },
  constructor: function (first, last) {
    this.partFirst = first;
    this.partLast = last;
  },
  beget: pd.Base.beget 
});

console.log(Name.beget("jimmy", "dean").toString())
console.log(Name.isPrototypeOf(Name.beget()));
console.log(String.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Name.beget()));
console.log(Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(Name.beget()));
console.log(Name.toString.call(Name.beget('jimmy', 'dean')));
console.log(Name.toString.call({
    partFirst: 'jimmy',
    partLast: 'dean'
}));
```

Of course output is as expected [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9zMYG/)

Comment: This is far uglier and verbose then the OP's own solution, not to mention the added need for a polyfill to account for any IE < 9 ...https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill

Comment: @jondavidjohn it can be polyfilled to work in IE6+ and all other major browsers

Comment: +1 for posting the obvious alternative. But I agree that the original is more elegant (provided the assignment of a String to *Name.prototype* is removed). I never understood the need for *Object.create*, it's a Crockfordism.

Comment: @RobG I prefer to not think in terms of constructors. Constructors are ugly, all you need is a prototype object. The only thing that's ugly with the Object.create solution is that instantiation and initialization is a two step thing

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

```
function subclass(constructor, superConstructor) {
    function surrogateConstructor() { }

    surrogateConstructor.prototype = superConstructor.prototype;

    var prototypeObject = new surrogateConstructor();
    prototypeObject.constructor = constructor;

    constructor.prototype = prototypeObject;
}



/* Base object */
function BaseItem() {
    this.type = 'baseitem';
    this.obj = null;
}
BaseItem.prototype.render = function() {
    return "foo";
}



/* Sub class */
function InteractionArea() {
    BaseItem.call(this);
    this.type = 'interactionarea'
    this.obj = document.createElement('div')
}
subclass(InteractionArea, BaseItem);

//here come the overrides
InteractionArea.prototype.render = function() {
    return "foobar";
}
InteractionArea.prototype.render2 = function() {
    return "foobar";
}



/* Sub-sub class */
function InteractionArea2() {
    InteractionArea.call(this);
    this.type = 'interactionarea2';
    this.obj = false;
}
subclass(InteractionArea2, InteractionArea);

InteractionArea2.prototype.render = function() {
    return "bar";
}
```