# Is this Javascript function efficient?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a list of nodes, which are html li elements

```
<ul id="nodesList">
   <li id="node_1">Node 1</li>
   <li id="node_2">Node 2</li>
   <li id="node_3">Node 3</li>
   <li id="node_4">Node 4</li>
   <li id="node_5">Node 5</li>
</ul>
```

I have a javascript function which manages these nodes

```
(function (nodesManager) {
    var nodes = [];
    nodesManager.requestNode = function(id) {
        if (nodes[id]) {
            return nodes[id];
        }

        nodes[id] = new Node(id);
        return nodes[id];
    }
} (window.nodesManager = window.nodesManager || {}));

var Node = function(id) {
    instance = this;

    var node = $("#node_" + id);

    this.changeName = function(newValue) {
        node.text(newValue);
    };

    // and other nodes specific functions

    var _properties = null;
    this.getProperties = function () {
        if (_properties !== null)
            return _properties;

        var response = null;
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Nodes/NodeProperties', // json object { "dateCreated": "10 minutes ago", "createdBy": "Mike" }
            data: { node_Id: id },
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                if (data.hasError) {
                    alert(data.message);
                } else {
                    response = data;
                }
             },
             error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('ajax error');
             }
        });
        _properties = response;

        return _properties;
    };
        this.resetProperties = function () {
            _properties = null;
        };
    }


$("#nodesList").delegate("li", "click", function() {
    var node_Id = $(this).attr("id").replace("node_", "");

    var newNodeName = "I am a new value";
    nodesManager.requestNode(node_Id).changeName(newNodeName);
});
```

My question is that if having the changeName function in the Node object affects performance?

Is it created for each node selected by user?

Is it better to put it inside nodesManager function so it is instantiated only once? or this doesn't matter...

**What is very important for me**

```
function getNodeCreatorUserName(id) {
    var properties = nodesManager.requestNode(id).getProperties();
    var userName = properties.createdBy;

    // do something with userName
};
function getNodeDateCreated(id) {
    var properties = nodesManager.requestNode(id).getProperties();
    var dateCreated = properties.dateCreated;

    // do something with dateCreated
};

getNodeCreatorUserName("1"); 
getNodeDateCreated("1");     // No server side call will be made because properties are already stored in Node object
```

Comment: Put them both into JSPerf (http://jsperf.com/) and see for yourself which is more performant. You might also checkout this post (http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/06/12/javascript-not-your-father-s-inheritance-model-part-2.aspx) to figure out how to add functions to a prototype. Functions defined on the prototype are only defined once and then referenced versus defined multiple times per object created.

Comment: [Codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit for this sort of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you're concerned by performance issues (keep in mind that a difference is hardly noticeable for a small amount of nodes), you should opt for prototype over closure, because they're (up to >50%) faster, see:

[Javascript prototype operator performance: saves memory, but is it faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493252/javascript-prototype-operator-performance-saves-memory-but-is-it-faster)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kristoffer/archive/2007/02/13/javascript-prototype-versus-closure-execution-speed.aspx

http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/

Comment: I will use prototyping instead for Node class. But the nodesManager closure is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

`Node` is already defined in `window`, you probably should call it something else.

Try something like this:

```
function MyNode (id) {
   this.node = $("#node_" + id);
}

MyNode.prototype.changeName = function(newValue) {
    this.node.text(newValue);
};
```

Comment: Ok, if i add a prototype how i will be able to select an individual node? nodesManager function takes care of not creating two Node objects if the object has already been created. I will always have to create a MyNode object when i want to work with a node? var node = MyNode("1"); node.changeName("whatever");

Comment: @RaraituL `new MyNode(id)`. I assumed your `Node` function was a constructor since it doesn't return anything and references `this`. What does `this` refer to in your `Node` function?

Comment: I am not very good at javascript and this is what i am trying to learn. Actualy for me `Node` is a container which holds data about each individual `<li>` element from the page. I use it also for storing specific properties for each node, like json object return from database. Before learning about this, i was always making an ajax request for the server each time a node was clicked. Now, once the properties has been loaded, i store them inside the Node object, and i can access them like `nodesManager.requestNode("1").getProperties()`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to squeeze cycles...

```
(function (nodesManager) {
    var nodes = [];
    nodesManager.requestNode = function(id) {
        // reduce number of checks
        return nodes[id] !== undefined ? nodes[id] : nodes[id] = new Node(id);
    }
} (window.nodesManager = window.nodesManager || {}));

$("#nodesList").delegate("li", "click", function() {
    // no need to wrap this in jQ just to get the id
    var node_Id = this.id.replace("node_", "");

    var newNodeName = "I am a new value";
    nodesManager.requestNode(node_Id).changeName(newNodeName);
});
```

If you really want to make that chunk of code more efficient, beyond squeezing cycles, we would need more insight into what it is trying to achieve.