# Why do Backbone and other libraries use _.extend, not prototype for classes?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, prototype

I've read an interesting article on [DOM prototype extension](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/), showing some good reasons to not always rely on prototypes of Element - I didn't know there were subclasses of elements, like

HTMLParagraphElement.prototype <-
  HTMLElement.prototype <-
  Element.prototype <-
  Node.prototype <-
  Object.prototype

In general, Object prototypes [can be used for subclassing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype#Examples), but often I see _.extend used to create mixins or base-classes, for example as seen in the Backbone source code.

```
_.extend(Model.prototype, Events, {...stuff...}
```

Why was this used instead of something like:

```
function innerModel() { ...stuff...}
innerModel.prototype = Events

Model.prototype = innerModel
```

Is the lack of prototype-chain visualization and debugging in browsers a reason _.extend is often used for subclassing instead of object's prototype?

Comment: Your suggested method means that anything added to Events gets added to all objects with Event in their prototype chain, which could potentially be very surprising.

Comment: Also, what is `{ ... stuff ... }`? In your first example, it would be something like `{ name: function () { ... } }`, in your second example, it would be the executable body of a function.

Comment: @meagar `innerModel` could be an object `{ name:function, other functions}`, or a `function() { this.name = function... this.otherfunction = function...}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why using Javascript object and not prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805491/why-using-javascript-object-and-not-prototype)