# Javascript classes, compiler performance and memory allocation on new Klass()

Tags: javascript

```
EDIT:
========================================================
Please see revision 13 of this test for answers: 
http://jsperf.com/closure-prototype-static-performance/
========================================================
```

I usually **prefer** to declare my klasses like this, as I am not a big fan of the object literal way:

**FIRST WAY: private scoping**

```
    function Employees() {
            var persons = []; // [Person, Person]

            this.isEmployed = function(_firstName, _lastName) {
                    for ( var i = 0; i < persons.length ; i++ ) {
                            if ( persons[i].equals(_firstName, _lastName) ) {
                                    return true;
                            }
                    }
                    return false;
            }
    }

    function Person(_firstName, _lastName) {
            this.equals = function(firstName, lastName) {
                    return _firstName == firstName && _lastName == lastName;
            }
    }
```

**SECOND WAY: prototype**

Alternative is to use the prototype but then you wouldn't get access to "private" properties such as var persons = [] and arguments in Person(...) but one might be able to live with making them public, although for person two new properties would be introduced:

```
    function Employees() {
            this.persons = []; // [Person, Person]
    }
    Employees.prototype.isEmployed = function(_firstName, _lastName) {
            for ( var i = 0; i < this.persons.length ; i++ ) {
                    if ( this.persons[i].equals(_firstName, _lastName) ) {
                            return true;
                    }
            }
            return false;
    };

    function Person(_firstName, _lastName) {
            this.firstName = _firstName;       // Two new properties. Are these or the function declared more expensive?
            this.lastName  = _lastName;
    }
    Person.prototype.equals = function(firstName, lastName) {
            return this.firstName == firstName && this.lastName == lastName;
    };
```

**THIRD WAY : static approach**

Another alternative is to do like the prototype stuff but instead make methods outside "static":

```
    function Employees() {
            this.persons = []; // [Person, Person]
    }
    function isEmployed(employee, _firstName, _lastName) {
            for ( var i = 0; i < employee.persons.length ; i++ ) {
                    if ( equals(employee.persons[i], _firstName, _lastName) ) {
                            return true;
                    }
            }
            return false;
    }
    function Person(_firstName, _lastName) {
            this.firstName = _firstName;       // Two new properties. Are these or the function declared more expensive?
            this.lastName  = _lastName;
    }
    function equals(person, firstName, lastName) {
            return person.firstName == firstName && person.lastName == lastName;
    }
```

**Questions:**

**1.**
Which one of these approaches would you say is **best for performance, memory** wise and cpu power, and is there any reason to why or when one should try to avoid or follow the other?

**2.**
Is the last example with the "static" scoping better than the prototype approach in this perspective?

**3.**
And when it comes to the first way, which is my prefered way, because it is more neat, allows for "private" scoping, and all code fits nicely in,
does the compiler maybe do the prototype approach for you, or are these functions declared over and over again for each new Person you do?

I try to avoid using the first approach when I do new() alot and when there is alot of methods involved, then I usually resort to the static approach, although I want to know if I have any real good reaoson to do this?

**4.**
I noticed my example didn't include a "**private**" function, and so how are they treated by the compiler?

Example:

```
    function Person(_firstName, _lastName) {
            function privateFunction() {
                    // How does the compile treat private functions. Are they also created once per new Person() ? Cheap or expensive?
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which one of these approaches would you say is best for performance, memory wise and cpu power?

See [Javascript prototype operator performance: saves memory, but is it faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3493252/1048572) and [Defining methods via prototype vs using this in the constructor - really a performance difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12180790/1048572). Prototypes do definitely save memory.

> Is there any reason to why or when one should try to avoid or follow it?

You'd use the privileged methods and scoped variables only if you really care about privacy.

> Is the last example with the "static" scoping better than the prototype approach?

The lookup might be a little cheaper, but don't care about that. Putting instance methods on the instances (or their prototypes) is cleaner and avoids global scope pollution.

> Does the compiler maybe do the prototype approach for you, or are these functions declared over and over again for each new Person you do?

Of course it's optimized by the interpreter (or at least the modern ones). The executable code will be shared, but to keep the specified semantics different function objects with different scope pointers will be created.

> I try to avoid using the first approach when I do new() alot and when there is alot of methods involved, then I usually resort to the static approach.

You can combine them of course. Probably not all of the many methods need access to the private variables, then you can put them on the prototype.

> I noticed my example didnt include a "private" function

Yes it did. The `employed` and `equals` function expression are just as private-scoped as a function declaration.

> Are they also created once per `new Person()`? Cheap or expensive?

Of course they are - once for every different scope. Not that expensive, but if could you made them static (put them out of the constructor scope) they would be cheaper.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Appreciate it, now I know :)

Comment: Cool to see that your first link contained the same type of questions and answers, including the static one :)

Comment: According to latest test, closure and prototype are almost identical :
http://jsperf.com/closure-prototype-static-performance

Comment: If you refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4041582/1048572), you should avoid those results. Nobody would use a constructor to create static functions. The test is basically comparing "*instantiating an object*" vs "*referencing a singleton*" - the latter is a noop and obviously faster. Your "static" approach is completely different. You time your own codes!

Comment: [Revision 12](http://jsperf.com/closure-prototype-static-performance/12) of that test case compares plain lookup times of static functions on static objects - no instantiation at all. Have a look at that :-)

Comment: However your last link, simply reuse Z over and over again, it is not a fair test, as the others have their new X() and new Y() in the for loop. More fair would be to create new X() once and do the same in the for loop. The test is a bit flawed.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said… Revison 12 does not create new objects in the loop any more.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but now Z is flawed as a new Object is created in the same manner. I get that the closure way is fastest on revision 12 which doesn't seem right. I created a new revision 13 which looks more like what I am trying to test. The results is as one could expect. I should probably post this as a new jsperf as it is a complete rewrita: http://jsperf.com/closure-prototype-static-performance/13  ... the results show that object literal comes first, and then prototype and static reference which is pretty much equal. Closure is slowest.

Comment: If one doesn't want to go the object literal way, which is the fastest, prototype or static is the way to go which I kind of makes sense. http://jsperf.com/closure-prototype-static-performance/13

Comment: Bergi, I saw you revision 14, however, I do not believe that the invokation of the method increment is the issue. But about the actual object creation. The for loop now likely levels out the playfield by removing minor time differences for the object creation that exists between them. Factory method with static reference in 13 was the fastest.

Comment: You're free to remove/lower the loop, though I think that multiple invocations of the method and accessing the `val` are essential for such tests (they were the reason to instantiate all those objects). [Revison 14](http://jsperf.com/closure-prototype-static-performance/14) was mostly created to **structure** the test cases better (and use less confusing names - "*closure by reference*" hardly makes sense).