# JavaScript performance optimization in defining object methods

Tags: javascript, performance, oop, optimization

What is the best way to define object methods in JavaScript taking into consideration performance.

Example one creates the object methods every time an instantiation is made with `new`.

```
function Person(first, last) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;

  this.fullName = function() {
    return this.first + ', ' + this.last;
  };
  this.fullNameReversed = function() {
    return this.last + ', ' + this.first;
  };
}

var me = new Person('Robert', 'Rocha');
```

Example two creates the object methods once and all instances share the same methods.

```
function Person(first, last) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
}

Person.prototype.fullName = function() {
    return this.first + ', ' + this.last;
  };

Person.prototype.fullNameReversed = function() {
    return this.first + ', ' + this.last;
  };

var me = new Person('Robert', 'Rocha');
```

Is there any performance advantages to either one?

Comment: Benchmark it yourself on jsperf

Comment: #1 does more work than #2, if the core doesn't cheat.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript prototype operator performance: saves memory, but is it faster?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493252/javascript-prototype-operator-performance-saves-memory-but-is-it-faster)

Comment: On Chrome using prototype is significantly faster when creating new objects but I have not seen any difference in performance when using the objects. Though using the prototype model does not allow for the use of closure within the object

Comment: Another thing I read is that those inner functions do not use the benefits of closures and take up more memory and processing speed as they are treated as closures. Thus assigning these methods to the prototype is recommended.