# Make TypeScript produce prototypes for ES6

Tags: typescript

Is it possible within the latest TypeScript to make specific class methods to be prototypes, even though the general target is ES6?

And as a side question - to have a specific class produce prototypes only.

Example of a TypeScript class:

```
class Test {
    constructor() {    
    }

    methodName() {   
    }
}
```

For ES6 as the general target it produces the same JavaScript code, while I want it to be:

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
    }
}

Test.prototype.methodName = function () {
}
```

i.e. either for a specific method or for all methods within the class I want to get prototypes instead, despite using ES6 as the general target.

---

The main reason for asking is as follows. I have a module that needs to create a very large number of such class instances, and after reading many posts here it seems the consensus is that prototypes will perform better in such a case:

- [Javascript prototype operator performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493252/javascript-prototype-operator-performance-saves-memory-but-is-it-faster)
- [Defining methods via prototype vs using this in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180790/defining-methods-via-prototype-vs-using-this-in-the-constructor-really-a-perfo)

---

P.S. I'm mostly interested in the server-side of things, i.e. Node.js 4-8.

Comment: What is the story behind this requirement? PS: ES2015 classes methods are available through `prototype`.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can you provide some samples?

Comment: "prototypes will perform better in such a case" --- it makes no sense: classes are implemented using prototypes.

Comment: @zerkms Prototyped methods versus class methods. What doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: @vitaly-t class (instance) methods **ARE** prototype methods.

Comment: The difference is declarative. And as the links I provided point out, the performance difference is real, unfortunately.

Comment: "he difference is declarative" --- how is it relevant to runtime performance? "And as the links I provided point out" --- I don't see in those anything about ES2015 classes. (not to say those questions and answers are 5-6 years old, while ES2015 was released in 2015).

Comment: Those links are nothing and have nothing to do with this. Using ES6 classes will generate the appropriate prototype methods. The links you're referring to is creating functions within the constructors and not placing them in the prototype. Of course _those_ will have bad performance in comparison, those functions are created every time a new instance is created.

Comment: @JeffMercado you may be right there! :)

Answer (score 3):

When this code

```
class Test {
    constructor() {    
    }

    methodName() {   
    }
}
```

is executed in es6-capable runtime, `methodName` **is** defined on the prototype:

```
console.log(typeof Test.prototype.methodName)
VM153:1 function
```

**UPDATE**

I created very simple test to compare performance of method defined in the class vs. assigned on the prototype. If [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/class-method-vs-prototype/1) results are to be believed, calling class method is 5% slower in Chrome 58, but prototype is 14 % slower in Firefox.

I'd suggest running actual performance tests with real data from your use cases, then filing appropriate bugs for Chrome and/or Firefox.

Comment: "calling class method is 5% slower in Chrome 58" --- not reproducible here.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to do this (source: I work on the TypeScript team).

Perhaps there's a follow-up question for why you would want to do this. AFAIK these two outcomes are almost indistinguishable behaviorally.