# Effectiveness of JS Object creation factory pattern vs. new

Tags: javascript, oop, factory

It would seem that using the vanilla JS model for object (in OOP sense) creation:

```
function Point(x,y) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
}

Point.prototype.distSquared = function(p) {
  return (this.x - p.x) * (this.x - p.x) + (this.y - p.y) * (this.y - p.y)
}
```

is more effective than factory pattern:

```
function makePoint(x,y) {

  const distSquared = (p) => {
    return (point.x - p.x) * (point.x - p.x) + (point.y - p.y) * (point.y - p.y)
  }

  let point = {
    x,
    y,
    distSquared
  }

  return point
}
```

because in the former case the public function `distSquared` is only declared once and all `Point`s share it -- it's property of their common prototype, while in the latter case every `Point` has its own copy of `distSquared`.

Is this intuition correct? Does it have some practical consequences in terms of memory consumption, performance and so on?

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Comment: Not the factor pattern, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493252/javascript-prototype-operator-performance-saves-memory-but-is-it-faster and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180790/defining-methods-via-prototype-vs-using-this-in-the-constructor-really-a-perfo

Comment: This isn't the factory pattern, though. It's just a function that returns a literal object. [Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) does not *require* plain objects to be created. The OOP factory pattern generalises over constructors and returns *an instance* but not necessarily a concrete instance. It's to be used with polymorphism. `makePoint()` could very well be implemented as `return new Point()` and would be a valid factory.

Comment: one practical consequence is that you should use classes for this kind of stuff.